# How to view packages provided by a PPA?

Tags: package-management, ppa

For example, I am trying to install the latest version of Gnome-Do, provided by the following PPA.

```
ppa:do-testers/ppa
```

However, I am unable to find the latest build.  Therefore I would like to search the available packages for the PPA so I can perform the install.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [tobu](https://serverfault.com/users/29107/tobu) in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/282804/180142):

Simple:

```
grep ^Package: /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_*_Packages
```

Or more flexible:

```
grep-dctrl -sPackage . /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_*_Packages
```

For fancier querying, use `apt-cache policy` and `aptitude` [as described here](https://superuser.com/questions/132346/find-packages-installed-from-a-certain-repository-with-aptitude/138726#138726):

```
aptitude search '~O LP-PPA-gstreamer-developers'
```

You shall modify the search queries to meet your requirements:

```
aptitude search '~O LP-PPA-do-tester'
```

Comment: Worked like a charm; I used the first option provided.  Turns out there are no packages for the example PPA in the original post...

Comment: `sudo apt-get update` my friend ;)

Comment: I did, but still nothing.  I will just find another way to update it :)

Comment: @AlexBrooks check `apt-cache policy <package_name>`, maybe you already have the latest version.